# Change the position of a selection box in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a selection box in an [html](/questions/tagged/html)`div`

```
<div id="selectionBox"></div>
```

I am trying to change the position of this box however the code below is not working. In a sense that the selection box stays where it is, it doesn't move at all.

Can someone please explain to me why this is not working and how I can fix it?

```
var select = d3.select("#selectionBox")
  .append('select')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 50 + ")")
    .attr('class', 'select')
    .text("Failure Mode")
    .on('change', onchange);
```

Comment: How is it not working? What does this do versus what do you want it to do?

Comment: it doesn't move the box from it's original position.

Comment: Change to `.attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "px," + 50 + "px)")`. Adding **`px`**.

Comment: About your approach, why not creating the select box in HTML/CSS in advance with `display: none` to make sure it's not displayed and then change only that property? That way, style/positional elements won't be in the JS file but will remain on the CSS side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code doesnt work try to change the css style of the element like this:

```
    document.getElementById("selectionBox").style = " margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; ";
    //Just fill it with your properties
```

Comment: This has worked! thank you very much. I still don't understand why the translate doesn't work even when I added the "px" that was missing...weird

Answer (score 0):

You forgot add **`px`** in `.attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 50 + ")")`.

See [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate).

Your code should be:

```
var select = d3.select("#selectionBox")
  .append('select')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "px," + 50 + "px)")
    .attr('class', 'select')
    .text("Failure Mode")
    .on('change', onchange);
```

**With `document.getElementById()`:**

You can use the **`setAttribute()`** method to add the `transform: translate(100px, 50px)` to the `selectionBox` element.

Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("selectionBox").setAttribute("style", "transform: translate(" + 100 + "px," + 50 + "px)");
```

Comment: it is still not working, the getElementById ones does. Thank you for your help though